# Send data over TCP socket from windows form application to universal app not working

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, uwp, tcpclient

I have Windows Universal Application as TCP server. So I want to send data over TCP socket.

It works, if I send data from Windows Universal Application as client. But I want to send data from Windows Forms Application and I can't use StreamSocket, so I tried to send data with client as its shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx and it doesn't working. So are there any limitations on comunication between UWP and classic windows forms, because I've tried many diferent options to make it working. So only way to make it work was like I said with UWP on both sides. I did check capabilities (Internet(Client), Internet(Client & Server), Private Networks(Client & Server)).

Here is code of TCP server:

```
private readonly int _port;
public int Port { get { return _port; } }

private StreamSocketListener listener;
private DataWriter _writer;

public delegate void DataRecived(string data);
public event DataRecived OnDataRecived;

public delegate void Error(string message);
public event Error OnError;

public SocketServer(int port)
{
    _port = port;
}

public async void Star()
{
    try
    {
        if (listener != null)
        {
            await listener.CancelIOAsync();
            listener.Dispose();
            listener = null;
        }

        listener = new StreamSocketListener();

        listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;
        await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(Port.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (OnError != null)
            OnError(e.Message);
    }
}

private async void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    var reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
    _writer = new DataWriter(args.Socket.OutputStream);
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
            if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
                return;                    
            uint stringLenght = reader.ReadUInt32();
            uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLenght);
            if (stringLenght != actualStringLength)
                return;
            if (OnDataRecived != null)
            {              
                string data = reader.ReadString(actualStringLength);
                OnDataRecived(data);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (OnError != null)
            OnError(ex.Message);
    }
}

public async void Send(string message)
{
    if (_writer != null)
    {
        _writer.WriteUInt32(_writer.MeasureString(message));
        _writer.WriteString(message);

        try
        {
            await _writer.StoreAsync();
            await _writer.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (OnError != null)
                OnError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: If the client is on the same computer, that won't work. [a Windows Runtime app that uses a DatagramSocket or StreamSocketListener to listen on an IP loopback address is prevented from receiving any incoming packets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh780593.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I know that, it is not on same computer.